# Slick Slider how to change options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I got a problem with the Slick Slider.
I want to change the 'slidesToShow 'option on every Slide.
Each slider page represents a group and only the right elements should show up on that page.
Each slide got a data-group attribute, which i´m using to count the elements and pass it to 'slickSetOption'.

https://jsfiddle.net/xnnm645x/3/

```
$('.slider').on('beforeChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) { 
   checkSlideToShow(nextSlide);
});
```

Why is there on the second page of the slider, still 4 elements instead of 3?

And if you scroll to the last slider page you can see how it change the width of the divs and suddenly becomes 3 slides. Is it possible to get rid of that transition effect?

Comment: okay, the slider seems to work now on my project. Now i just need it to change the slides without that ugly effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not working because slick will inject 2 div in your .slider element for its functionality.

you can check it by logging in console

```
console.log($('.slider div')) // count will be 11 and it will break your logic.
```

You need to found the div with data attribute only.

```
$('.slider div *[data-group]') // count will be 9
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/fydo8pt3/

Comment: yes! now its working, thank you.

Do you now how i can get that result, without that transition? I dont want the user to see it.

Comment: @Cornykid let me give a try. Will message you back

Comment: @Cornykid how about https://jsfiddle.net/ukt29aL5/ ??  the speed can make the bad transition not visible very clearly.

Comment: NP . glad i could help :)